# Providing Template Paths in flask.render_template

Tags: python, flask, directory, filepath, relative-path

I'm new to python and learning how to use flask for the first time. I'd like to render an html template `index.html` in a simple `app.py` file. My project directory is structured as follows:

```
- webapp_project
  - templates
    - index.html
  - modules
    - app.py
```

When I run `render_template("index.html")` in `app.py`, I get a `TemplateNotFound` exception, but if I move `app.py` to the same level as `templates` in the directory, it works. Clearly `render_template()` has trouble finding files that require going upstream in the directory tree, but I'm used to putting all my python code in its own folder as I did above. (I think this is good practice?) I tried writing `render_template("../templates/index.html")`, which would work for similar functions, like `open()`, that require file paths, but it doesn't work in this case.

Three questions:

1. Is there a simple way to fix this without changing the way my directory is arranged?
2. If not, is it a sign that I should be organizing my python projects differently than I've been doing?
3. Surely I'll be dealing with many more functions down the road that require a filepath to find a file. How consistent will these functions be in how they expect me to provide the name of the file being accessed?

Answer (score 0):

You must note that by default Flask looks for templates in a ***templates*** subfolder located inside your application folder (where your app.py is).

However it is possible with Flask to structure your code using [Blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/views/). Blueprints allow you to divide your code into different modules.

More concretely, this is the structure of a basic application with Flask:

```
webapp_project/
|
├── static/
|   ├── logo.png
|   ├── main.css
|   └── main.js
|
├── templates/
|   └── index.html
|
└──app.py
```

You can take advantage of blueprints to structure your code more intuitively by dividing it into modules; which facilitates the maintenance of the code and the reuse of certain modules in other projects...

```
webapp_project/
|
├── auth/
|   ├── templates/
|   |   └── auth/
|   |       ├── login.html
|   |       └── signup.html
|   |
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── auth.py
|
├── general/
|   ├── templates/
|   |   └── general/
|   |       └── index.html
|   |
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── general.py
|
├── static/
|   ├── logo.png
|   ├── main.css
|   └── main.js
|
├── app.py
└── models.py
```

[This tutorial](https://realpython.com/flask-blueprint/) is excellent for understanding in a practical way how to use blueprints to structure a Flask project.

**Edit**

To specifically answer your question, I will add that the advantage with Flask is the flexibility it offers in the way of structuring your code. It does not impose a specific structure on you.

What I described above was the default behavior, but you can change it. here's how:

Suppose you have this structure

```
webapp_project/
|
├── static/
|   ├── logo.png
|   ├── main.css
|   └── main.js
|
├── templates/
|   └── index.html
|
└── module
    └── app.py
```

All you have to do is add this in **module/app.py** :

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates', static_folder='../static')
```

Here you pass the arguments `template_folder` and `static_folder` to the Flask constructor when creating the application instance, which changes the default behavior of Flask by forcing it to fetch templates and static files from the specified locations.

Comment: I see. But even in your blueprints example, app.py is still at the topmost level of the directory, and not contained within a package. Is this the standard/expected place to put it?

Comment: @NickA. I just edited my answer to address your concern.